# when is the alternate for this plugin jquery-ui-1.8.6.custom.min.js

Tags: jquery-ui

when i use jquery-ui-1.8.6.custom.min.js  this plugin  some ui issues are comming Please let me know if any other alternative for this Plugin .

Comment: You haven't specfied _what_ plugin. Do you mean jQuery UI itself, or a plugin that uses jQuery UI? Also what UI issues are occuring? Flesh out your question more, you'll likely get an answer, if not this is just close fodder.

Answer (score 0):

You've probably forgotten to include the appropriate style sheets.  See [here](http://jqueryui.com/docs/Getting_Started), but in short you'll need something like this (obviously with your version numbers).

```
<link type="text/css" href="css/themename/jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.css" rel="Stylesheet" />  
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: can you send me the link for download js/jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.min.js

Comment: The website provides full instructions.